# winium.cruciatus vs winium.desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

**As per the link https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Cruciatus**

> Winium.Cruciatus is an open source C# Framework for automated testing of Windows application based on WinFroms and WPF platforms.

**As per the link https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop**

> Winium.Desktop is Selenium Remote WebDriver implementation for automated testing of Windows application based on WinFroms

My question is:

Both are open source projects and used for windows forms,wpf automation. If both are for same purpose then, in winium.Desktop project why Cruciatus assembly used and what is the purpose.

Note: Both are developed by same group i.e., 2gis

Answer (score 2):

**Why was Cruciatus not enough**

> Almost all teams that were dealing with internal 2GIS products used Cruciatus. Each of the teams suggested improvements for the tool. So, in order to please everyone, we have reworked the Cruciatus logic completely, together with ruining its reverse compatibility. It was painful, but useful.
>
> Besides, we have abandoned Mouse and Keyboard classes from CodedUI in order to eliminate dependence on libraries that are delivered together with Visual Studio. It means that we have learned to assemble a project on public CI servers like AppVeyor.
>
> As a result, we have created a convenient and a self-contained tool that solves all our problems with access to Windows-based desktop applications. However, Cruciatus still has one crucial limitation, namely C# dictatorship.

Source - [techblog.badoo.com](https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2016/01/25/winium-desktop-selenium-for-windows-based-desktop-applications/)

Comment: Please use the citation character > for cited content